# how to get json response from android and save it in mysql database using cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.4

How i get the request params from android and decode it before save to the database?

This is my code:

```
public function insertSurvey() {
   $data = $this->request->data['surveyJSON'];

   $newData = $this->set('_serialize',$data);

   $this->SurveyReport->save($newData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php

$json_to_php_array = $this->request->input('json_decode', TRUE); 

?>
```

I think this is what you are looking for?

The above decodes the JSON array that has been Posted.